# Is it coincidential that $\left(\frac{px^a}{qx^b}\right)^x$ always intersects $\frac{p^x\cdot x^a\cdot x}{q^x\cdot x^b\cdot x}$ once

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Take for example, $x^x=(\frac {x}{1})^x $, then it will have one point of intersection with $\frac {x^2}{x}=x $

Or $\left(\frac{2x^2}{3x^3}\right)^x\implies\frac{2^x\cdot x^3}{3^x\cdot x^4}$

Also works with: $\left(\frac{x^2}{x^4}\right)^ {x^2}\implies\frac{x^4}{x^6}$

Shorter rule: One point of intersection $r$ such that  $\left(\frac{px^a}{qx^b}\right)^x=\frac{p^x\cdot x^{a+1}}{q^x\cdot x^{b+1}}$

Note: One point of intersection from the interval $x>0$.

Comment: $x=1$ is always a solution, in fact, the only one.  Just set the two expressions equal and solve.

Comment: That's funny, why does it work though ?

Comment: formatting tip:  Please use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or juxtaposition when multiplying (instead of $*$).  So use $a\cdot b$ or $ab$ when denoting the multiplication of a with b, instead of using $a*b$.

Comment: $\left(\frac{2x^2}{3x^3}\right)^x\neq\frac{2^x\cdot x^3}{3^x\cdot x^4}$

$\left(\frac{x^2}{x^4}\right)^ {x^2}\neq\frac{x^4}{x^6}$

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for solutions of $$
\left(\frac{px^a}{qx^b}\right)^x=\frac{p^xx^{a+1}}{q^xx^{b+1}}
$$
That is,$$
\frac{p^xx^{ax}}{q^xx^{bx}}=\frac{p^xx^{a+1}}{q^xx^{b+1}}$$
Now we can cancel $p^x/q^x$ and then subtract exponents to get $$
x^{(a-b)x}= x^{a-b}$$
Now the exponents must be equal, so either $a=b$ or $x=1$.

In the trivial case that $a=b$ it's true for every $x>0$.  Otherwise, $x=1$ is the only solution.

Comment: But why if you take $(\frac{5^1/x\cdot x^{1/x}}{1^{1/x}})^x$, every single value of x is valid, and not just x=1?

Comment: That's a different question.  If you want to ask it it, you should post a new question.  Be sure to explain what you mean by "$x$ is valid."